# find the matching number of characters between two strings

Tags: string

Here's the problem:

There are two strings inputted from the user.

For each character in the same positions of two strings respectively:

1 and 1 means 0,
2 and 2 means 0,
3 and x means 2,
nothing means 2

Comment: The indentation of your code example is botched but you seem to return from the loop after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you probably want to use the `==` comparison between logical values, but you have not put the two expressions into `()`.
Try e.g.

```
    if (ord(x) in range(48,57)) == (ord(y) in range(48,57)):
        same_type += 1
```

On the other hand you are using the conditions as independent `if` statements, so multiple such conditions will be true in `spec_dist2`. I don't think this is your intention.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. For the function `spec_dist2` the characters can be in only one range and of course for all other ranges the `not in` will result False. E.g. you have the characters 'a' and 'e' are in  `range(97,122)` and you will get `True` for all other ranges they don't belong to, because False==False equals True. An other question is what should happen if the strings are not equal length.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in that case:

```
def spec_dist1(string1, string2):
  same_type = 0
  for x, y in zip(string1, string2):
      if x == y:
          same_type += 0
      elif ord(x) in range(48,57) and ord(y) in range(48,57):
          same_type += 1
      elif any(ord(x) in range(s,e) for s,e in [(97,122), (65,90)]) and any(ord(y) in range(s,e) for s,e in [(97,122), (65,90)]):
          same_type += 1
      elif any(ord(x) in range(s,e) for s,e in [(33,47), (58,64), (91,96), (123,126)]) and any(ord(y) in range(s,e) for s,e in [(33,47), (58,64), (91,96), (123,126)]):
          same_type += 1
      else:
          same_type += 2
  same_type += abs(len(string1) - len(string2)) * 3
  return same_type
```

Comment: If I follow what you said, 1 and 1 means 0, 2 and 2 means 0, 3 and x means 2 and ? and nothing means 2 right ?

Comment: Ok, I will edit then